# customize a CSV-file in PowerShell and export it

Tags: powershell, csv

We are supposed to edit a CSV-file in PowerShell and export the file afterwards

The CSV-file contains:

```
"ID";"date";"number"
"YYY-12345";"24.01.2023";"123456910"
```

Now we should add "-001" after the ID-block..but for the whole column

thats the code for now:

```
$folder_csv = 'C:\Abschluss'
$folder_fileout = 'C:\Abschluss\Ausgabe'

$files = Get-ChildItem $folder_csv -File -Filter *.csv 
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $data = Import-csv $($file.Fullname) -Delimiter ";" 
    foreach($dataset in $data) {
        $data.ID + "-001"
        $data | export-csv "$folder_fileout\test.txt" -Delimiter ";" -NoType -Encoding UTF8 -append
    }
}
```

it shows the results in the console of PowerShell but not in the created .txt-file.

Comment: At least you didn't say "extort".

Comment: You're looking to "update" the `ID` property, hence, `$data.ID + "-001"` should be `$data.ID = $data.ID + "-001"`

Comment: You're currently merging all Csvs into 1 file (`"$folder_fileout\test.txt"`), are you looking to do this or actually want to export each file separately ?

Comment: If I edit the code like that then I get a error code: The property "ID" was not found for this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
In C:\closure\powershell.ps1:8 characters:9
+ $data.ID = $data.ID + "-001"

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I am looking to do that yes

Comment: Sorry, `$data` is the complete collection of objects, you want `$dataset.ID = $dataset.ID + "-001"` (each element being enumerated)

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close with your code, the main issue is that you're currently doing `$data.ID + "-001"` and `$data` is actually the complete array of objects, you want to refer to `$dataset` instead (the object being enumerated). Aside from that, it seems you're looking to merge all Csvs into one, hence you could leverage the PowerShell pipeline using an outer [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2) loop instead of [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.3):

```
$folder_csv = 'C:\Abschluss'
$folder_fileout = 'C:\Abschluss\Ausgabe'

Get-ChildItem $folder_csv -File -Filter *.csv | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($line in $_ | Import-csv -Delimiter ';') {
        # update the Id property of this object
        $line.Id = $line.Id + '-001'
        # output the updated object
        $line
    }
} | Export-Csv "$folder_fileout\test.txt" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```